# mysql_query in PHP containing variables returning mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My code, which archives old members from a membership database, when run, returns

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM members WHERE member_ref = 155' at line 5.

It should copy the entry to the identical 'archive' table from 'members' and delete the original in members.

```
$ref = '155';

$leave = mysql_query("  INSERT INTO archive 
                        SELECT *
                        FROM members
                        WHERE member_ref = ".$ref.";
                        DELETE FROM members
                        WHERE member_ref = ".$ref ) or die(mysql_error());
```

I know I should be using mysqli but I haven't had time to standardise the whole system (~120 pages) from mysql to mysqli.

It's parsing 155 into the second $ref

Using the phpmyadmin's SQL window and entering the following works perfectly.

```
INSERT INTO archive 
                        SELECT *
                        FROM members
                        WHERE member_ref = 155;
                        DELETE FROM members
                        WHERE member_ref = 155
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You cannot have two seperate queries in one statement. Unless you specify a different separator than the default one (`;`). Its best practice however to have one statement for one job.

Comment: @paskl you confuse me. ; is the separator, no?

Comment: See the manual, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php. `mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported)`

Answer (score 2):

Use Separate Call, like this, [See Details About mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

```
$leave = mysql_query("  INSERT INTO archive 
                        SELECT *
                        FROM members
                        WHERE member_ref = '$ref' ") or die(mysql_error());

$leave = mysql_query("  DELETE FROM members
                        WHERE member_ref = '$ref'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the PHP Manual, it is written right on the first line:

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Therefore you should put your queries in separate `mysql_query()` calls.